# Why is this javascript function from an externally linked file undefined in my Rails view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've written a view that lives in `app/views/jobs/show.html.erb` and if I add the following code into my HTML everything works as I expect it to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        var $data = <%= raw @job_data %>;

        AddRow = function (data_row, table_id) {
            $(table_id).append
            (
             '<div class="row">' +
                 '<div class="col-md-5">' + data_row.Id + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Owner + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Status + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Actions.length + '</div>' +
             '</div>'
            );
        }

        PopulateDataTable = function (data, table_id) {
            for(i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
            AddRow(data[i], table_id);
            }
        }
        PopulateDataTable($data, "#jobtable");
});
</script>
```

However, leaving all that javascript in my view is rather messy and I want to pull it out into a separate .js file. So I've tried this:

1) Create a new file: `app/assets/javascripts/jobs.js`

2) Place this into the `jobs.js`:

```
        AddRow = function (data_row, table_id) {
            $(table_id).append
            (
             '<div class="row">' +
                 '<div class="col-md-5">' + data_row.Id + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Owner + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Status + '</div>' +
                 '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Actions.length + '</div>' +
             '</div>'
            );
        }

        PopulateDataTable = function (data, table_id) {
            for(i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
            AddRow(data[i], table_id);
            }
        }
```

3) Link to the new file in the `show.html.erb` and remove the code I've extracted. Here's what `show.html.erb` looks like now:

```
<script src="/assets/jobs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        var $data = <%= raw @job_data %>;
        PopulateDataTable($data, "#jobtable");
});
</script>
```

After moving the javascript into the external file (and linking to it) the page fails to load properly. I checked the server logs and see that the GET call to myfile.js went through without error. However, when looking at the browser debugger I see the following:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'PopulateDataTable' is undefined
```

What's going on? Is this a scope issue? Am I improperly linking to the external javascript with the  tag? Do I need to enclose it in the `$(function() { ... });` block?

I've tried too many combinations of things to count. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not a JS expert, but AFAIK `$(function() { });` creates a scope and functions defined inside aren't available outside. You may very well detect if page contains required element (`#jobtable`) and run the function only then, from inside the js file. Remember to make sure that DOM is ready though (either through jQuery or otherwise)

Comment: @MichalSzyndel But he's not defining the function inside `$(function() {...})` in the external JS file.

Comment: @Barmar given strange formatting of jobs.s excerpt I bet he is.

Comment: Also, since he doesn't use `var FunctionName =`, he's defining global functions, not local functions.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel What strange formatting? Looks like he just cut and pasted it, the formatting is fine.

Comment: @Barmar If SO taught me anything it's not to trust OP input entirely ;)

Comment: There is no reason why this should fail as presented. In fact, I tried emulating the behaviour in a Rails project and it worked perfectly.

Make sure you've pasted the contents of the files exactly. Also, ensure that jobs.js is loading, not myfile.js as you wrote in the question. Finally, make sure your jobs.js is included after JQuery.

Comment: As a general point, I tend to shy away from putting any JS directly into the HTML nowadays. I would prefer to put the entire set of JS functionality inside a single .js file, then add the data to a data-job attribute on the #jobtable tag itself. It is a simple matter to read this data (using `$.parseJSON($("#jobtable").data("job"))` for example) inside a `$(function() { ... });` block. Also you can add this file to your application.js to have it automatically loaded by the asset pipeline. If some weird typo is blocking you and you can't find it, trying a different approach may just fix it.

Comment: The jobs.js file I posted is a copy-paste of the entire contents of jobs.js. Similarly, the code from the show.html.erb is a copy-paste. I made no changes.

Comment: re: typo - if I copy paste the code and move it from jobs.js into the html so that the show.html.erb is as you see in the first code paste above, then the page loads just fine. If I cut and paste to move the two function definitions into jobs.js, then the page does not load (i.e. PopulateTableData is undefined)

Comment: The other piece of the puzzle is: how do I load @job_data (an embedded ruby var) in an externally-linked javascript file if it's not passed to the file from the HTML <script> block?

Comment: There's a Railscast about this issue, giving a few different solutions. One is using the data-xxx attribute as I mentioned above.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: To help find out what's going on with your current code, try putting a `console.log("Start")` at the top of your jobs.js file and `console.log("End");` below the end of the definition of PopulateDataTable. Then check your JS console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the face of it there isn't any reason why this isn't working. In fact, I replicated the process in a rails project and it worked fine. There's likely something going on that isn't mentioned in the OP, unfortunately.

However, stylistically I would not approach things this way to begin with. Defining functions in the global namespace is messy and can lead to conflicts as projects get larger. It's also good practice to separate concerns and not have any JS in the mark-up. This aids clarity and modularity of code as projects increase in complexity.

A better pattern is to place all the JS relating to a feature in one file that gets loaded automatically using the asset pipeline. An initializer JS file looks for the existence of the HTML nodes that are affected and conditionally initialises the JS. For example:

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
// ...
//= require jquery
// ...
//= require_tree ./features/
//= require initializer
// ...
```

app/assets/javascripts/features/my_feature.js:

```
MyApp = MyApp || {}
MyApp.MyFeature = function() {
  var doStuff = function() {
    // Feature functionality. Locate data and manipulate DOM.
  };
  return {
    init: function () { doStuff(); }
  };
};
```

app/assets/javascripts/initializer.js

```
$(function() {

  // ...

  if($('#relevant-tag').length > 0) {
    Myapp.MyFeature.init();
  }

  //...

});
```

Then the problem is how to pass the data into the DOM so that it can be read using JS. I tend to use something like a script tag of type "text/json", containing just JSON, which can be trivially read using the 'text' method on a JQuery object. Other options include using data-xxx attributes on tags (like the tag that's being manipulated for example). There's also the 'gon' gem, which uses a JS script tag... But namespaces your data in a much nicer way.

Ryan Bates covers the issue with far more aplomb than I:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Finally, I consider such patterns as:

```
'<div class="col-md-5">' + data_row.Id + '</div>'
```

to be a code smell in JS. I would consider using a template library such as MustacheJS. This allows the templates to be generated server-side if you wish (placed in special template files which you can include), so you can keep all mark-up in the same place. And the JQuery version of Mustache is pretty awesome.

But that's just me.

Comment: If you're just defining functions, it doesn't depend on anything being loaded yet. The dependencies aren't needed until the functions are _called_.

Comment: Post reworked based on deeper understanding of issue.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I'll re-read this a few times and try to incorporate more of the tips.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to say this, but it's fixed and I don't know why. Perhaps someone can teach me the proper stackoverflow process for this type of thing?

show.html.erb was modified to have the following in order to pass the data from controller to view:

```
<script id="jobs_data_field" type="text/json">
    <%= raw @job_data %>
</script>
```

jobs.js was then moved into a subfolder: app/assets/javascripts/jobs/load-table-data.js, and the contents was modified to read like this to pull the data from the view HTML to into a json object.

```
$(function() {
    var some_data_json = $("#jobs_data_field").html();
    var some_data = $.parseJSON(some_data_json);

    var AddRow = function (data_row, table_id) {
        $(table_id).append
    (
     '<div class="row">' +
         '<div class="col-md-5">' + data_row.Id + '</div>' +
         '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Owner + '</div>' +
         '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Status + '</div>' +
     '<div class="col-md-2">' + data_row.Actions.length + '</div>' +
     '</div>'
    );
    }

    var PopulateDataTable = function (data, table_id) {
        for(i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
            AddRow(data[i], table_id);
        }
    }

    PopulateDataTable(some_data, "#jobtable");
});
```

The load-table-data.js was automatically loaded by the asset train and I see the following in the console output:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jobs/load-table-data.js?body=1"></script>
```

The page is now loading as expected.